# when I open the website it doesn't load the products from the database mysql

Tags: database, web, product

I am trying to upload a php website and it does not load the products from the database
I exported the database with a sql file and I added it to the new database of the website
that I am uploading.
Nevertheless, only the slider of the website is working and the products, that are supposed
to be loaded, whenever I try to click on them on the menu, they do not show up.
¿What should I do to make it load the products?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for people to answer your question well, we will need more information. Can you post the content of the php file that is supposed to be generating the list of clickable products, along with the php file that is supposed to show each product's details? That will get the process started. Again, welcome.

Comment: hello, how can I upload a file? I don't know, I'm a newbie here. Thanks

Comment: No worries. If you edit your question, you will see a button in the button bar that looks like a pair of brackets. Like this: {}. You can paste your code into the question, then format it with that button. Alternatively, if you feel that the code is too long for inclusion in the question, you could link out to code hosted at gist.github.com.

Comment: make sure the login credentials for the remote db are correct. it's super easy to have a local dev db with one password, while your remote server has a different password. i usually try to account for this in my db connection. just check if you're local or remote and establish the conn accordingly.

Comment: https://github.com/hihi25/yeh/blob/1e23f6e962da87986acb9b9a8b3a667c1c3cc6e7/index.php

Comment: https://github.com/hihi25/yeh/blob/1e23f6e962da87986acb9b9a8b3a667c1c3cc6e7/producto.php

Comment: I wrote the permalink of the files

Comment: Are you getting any error output in your server's PHP error logs or in the browser? If so, please edit the question to include them. If not, try temporarily setting a lower error reporting threshold via the logic shown here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-display-errors-in-php-file ... and then edit your question to include the error or warning text. :-)

Comment: Hello, I haven't gotten any error. this is the website https://evet.turkok.online/

Comment: whenever I click on the products of the menu they don't load anything, that's the database problem

Comment: It looks like there's an ajax call out to get_all_products.php. If you replicate that POST request in Postman, are you then able to see error information?